# Player skip 8 bytes from mp4 start

Tags: html, video-streaming, mp4, jwplayer

Currently I have a .mp4 file that works correctly in any player (Native, Jwplayer, fluidplayer), I manually add 8 bytes to it at the beginning and it stops working.

The question I have, is if you know how to skip the 8 bytes that I add manually in the player?

I've been looking for more than two days to modify the range bytes of the header so that when it is start = 0, change it to start = 8, but I can't find that.

Do you know if any player gives you the option to edit the first request made to mp4? Can you think of another way?

Comment: The following code works for me https://pastebin.com/myKAB3Ri what I do is when the byte range start is 0, I change it to 8 and everything works correctly. But I would like to do it by editing some player like JWplayer, Fluidplayer or the native browser

Answer (score 0):

“Can you think of another way?” Yes, don’t corrupt the file by adding data to it. Mp4 files have a structure and the player expects that structure to be valid. By changing it you have corrupted the file.

Comment: I think that if I am considering this solution it is because I am convinced that I need this (mostly educational purposes), in theory if I add bits to a file and then pass them by, it does not affect the file at all. Moreover, I have managed to do it but in an ineffective way by creating a "own" player